# jQuery reset button reset complete event

Tags: jquery

The regular `<input type='reset'>` resets the form to its initial document.ready state but does not invoke the change() event of `<select>` despite the value changed.

I want to force the change event by directly calling `$('select').change()` but I need to call it after the reset complete, what is the complete() event of the reset button that I should listen to? Is there a "resetcomplete" event on the button?

A 2 year old post on jQuery forums suggest to use a timeout function to delay the `.change()`. Is there a new way of doing things now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I could have read this wrong, but are you looking for something similar to:

```
$(document).on("click", "input[type='reset']", function(){
   $("select").trigger("change");
});
```

So whenever the user `click`s the `reset` button, you `trigger` a `change` event for any `select`s.

**EDIT:**

Get the request from the click event and prevent the default behavior, reset the form and then trigger the change:

```
$(document).on("click", "input[type='reset']", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  form = e.toElement.form;
  form.reset();  
  $("select",form).trigger("change");
});
```

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseWest/JEeWw/2/)**

Comment: I'd assume at the moment this event handler is called, the values have not been reset yet. But I don't know. It's just something to evaluate.

Comment: Yeah, I just created a fiddle example here to test it: http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseWest/JEeWw/1/ This is in fact correct.

Comment: @Jake - See if the updated code above helps you any. If it doesn't then just let me know and I'll try to help further. Thanks